# check clicked element has class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my menu list. i need check if list item has specific class.

When I click the close button, I need to check if list item has *active* class.

My jQuery code is as below. but its not working.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    alert("active Yes");
  }
  else{
    alert("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#"> one</a> 
    <button onclick="close()"> Close</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"> two</a> 
    <button onclick="close()"> Close</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I check if *li* has *active* class?

Comment: Checkout my answer, you need just to check for the li element which is the parent of the clicked button

Answer (score 0):

Select it with closest

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var btn = $(this);
  var li = btn.closest('li');
  var isActive = li.hasClass('active');
  console.log(isActive);
});
```

Comment: can u help me to modify my script

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the parent element of the `<button>` which is the `<li>` element that has the class or not

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    alert("active Yes");
  }else {
    alert("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="active">
     <a href="#"> one</a> 
    <button onclick="close()"> Close</button>
    </li>
  <li>
<a href="#"> two</a> 
    <button onclick="close()"> Close</button>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: can use your code inside the angular js function 
 $scope.close = function( ) {  your code} like this.
button is 'ng-click'.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't use Angular before, so I have no idea